# Java code in Netbeans works but executing jar through cmd prompt gives nosuchmethod error exception

Tags: java, netbeans, apache-poi

i have made a Java program in Netbeans to edit Excel file using poi libraries
the code works fine in Netbeans but after building the jar file and executing it through command prompt gives a error when a call to some function is made that is there is external jar.

However i have included the target code in bulid.xml.. the jar file created in store also doesnot work and also the jar file created in dist folder also gives this error:

`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Nosuchmethoderror: org.apache.xmlbeans.xmloptions.setsaveaggresivenamespaces()Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/xmloptions;`

I have checked the class `org.apache.xmlbeans.xmloptions` is present in the jar file.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Nosuchmethoderror:
```

It seems you have wrong version of jars in classpath. Either lower version (or) higher version of jar than your code.

> i have checked the class org.apache.xmlbeans.xmloptions

It is not complaining about class not found, but it is saying the class available in classpath has different method signature than what you are calling in your code.

Example:  `Jar has method add(int a, int b); but your code calling(int a);`

Comment: Out of interest, how do you know its a version problem from this exception?  Or are you assuming this is the case since it cannot find the method but can find the class?

Comment: @JonTaylor: NoSuchMethodError errors happen most of the times when class versions are changed. See my updated answer.

Comment: good to know, I guess I'm lucky I've never actually had that exception come up in any of my code haha. Makes sense though :).

Comment: I m not calling any such method directly... the code works absolutely fine in netbeans.. can you elaborate on the version problem..

Comment: Finout what version of jars you have in netbeans project lib folder and make sure same version of jars exists in runtime classpath also.